# Input show the number of form fields with data (jQuery)

Tags: php, jquery, forms, input, formula

I have a long form and I need to count the number of inputs and textareas that have data inside them.  I need an input field that will display a number representing the number of inputs and textareas that have data within my form.

I prefer jquery or PHP.

Are there any examples out there or suggestions?

Thanks.
Erik

Comment: jQuery or PHP??? Are complementary dude! no competition..

Comment: @Erik Should it show only text inputs and textareas that are not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery you can just use this

```
var number = $('#form').find('input, textarea')
                       // filter out every empty input/textarea
                       .filter(function() { return $(this).val() == ''; })
                       .length;
```

Comment: I didn't downvote :) I do not have enough points yet. Anyway, it was just a question.

Comment: Yeah no offense at all :) I already updated my answer again, because I forgot  one important point.

Comment: I understand the function, but how do I make it appear in an input field within the form?

Comment: In short like this: `$('#form').on('change', function() { // my code from above .... $('.yourInput').val('There are '+ number + ' filled input fields'); });`. So on *any* formular change `.yourInput` will be updated.

Comment: It's not working based on what I see.  Here is a link:  http://jsfiddle.net/eriksnet/GMpQm/1/

Comment: Ok you need at least jQuery 1.7 for this or you need to change `.on('change'` to `.change(`. Here's my updated version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GMpQm/10/

Answer (score 1):

You could do an onkeypress function that runs and updates your div with the number of fields that have data.

Off the top of my head but maybe:

```
function tallyFields() {

var totalFilledFields = 0;
var fieldAVal = document.getElementByID("fieldA").value;
// add more fields here the same way

if(fieldAVal.length > 0) {
 totalFilledFields++;
}
// check more fields here the same way and increment the same var

document.getElementByID("yourTotalDiv").innerHTML=totalFilledFields;

}
```

Assigning this function onkeypress of each of your form fields might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$(".myform :input").length;
```

Comment: This also retrieves `<select>`

Comment: So if I add an input like this it would work?  <input class=".myform" type="text">  This will give me the number of fields with data in the form?